# Why does VSCode freeze when there is a ton of terminal output (Ubuntu)?

Tags: python, ubuntu, visual-studio-code, terminal

I have a program that prints the rgba of all the pixels in an image using PIL. The problem is that when I run the program *in VSCode*, it prints a second or so of output, and then freezes. My whole computer then freezes, and I have to power it off and restart it.

However, when I run the program *in the GNOME terminal*, it completes successfully. Could anyone tell me why VSCode does this, and if there is a way to prevent it? (in other words, what is the difference between the GNOME terminal and the VSCode terminal?)

The code:

```
import PIL
from PIL import Image

image = Image.open("/home/user/i.jpg")
for i in image.getdata():
    print(i, end="")
```

Here is the image I am using:

[image: /home/user/i.jpg]

This problem is not specific to the image code, this code is just a good way to demonstrate the kind of code that causes this error. I'm using Python 3.8.10 in VSCode 1.52.1 on an Ubuntu 20.04.2.

Comment: `print(i, end="", flush=True)`

Comment: VSCode still freezes when I run it with `print(i, end="", flush=True)`. The question was why VSCode *specifically* froze, while the GNOME terminal did not. If that wasn't clear in the question, please let me know how to improve.

Comment: I thought that flush stdout could help. Will be good to add "Ubuntu" to question title though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like just because the picture which you are using is too large that caused too many outputs, I have tried some litter images and it works well.

**Update:**

The terminal was integrated into the VSCode. It has been customed, so it has different strategies such as memory strategy.

And looks like we should avoid outputs too much data in the integrated terminal in the VSCode. Some people have run across the [same issue](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/105030).

And it looks like increasing the size of the terminal panel is helpful to outputs the data more smoothly.

Comment: Thanks for the input, but this doesn't answer the question. The question was: *why* does printing a large output freeze VSCode, and *not* the GNOME terminal. In other words, what's the difference between the GNOME terminal and the VSCode terminal?

Comment: @Sam Matzko Could you have a look at the update of this answer? thanks.

Comment: Thanks for updating! This is much more clear. I'm glad I'm not the only one having this issue. I will upvote and accept your answer.